# Как разместить БД в App_Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity

Как правильно оформить строку подключения, чтобы ЮД генерировалась в конкретной папке, а именно App_Data? Простите что такой короткий вопрос, просто найти никак не могу.

Comment: А БД уже создана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnectionName"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```